# Why does Task.WaitAll() not block or cause a deadlock here?

Tags: c#, xamarin, task-parallel-library, async-await

In the example below two `await` calls are used. To gain performance, the sample gets converted `Task.WaitAll()` instead (not really any faster, but this is just an example).

This is code from a library using Sqlite.Net on Android and the method gets called from `OnResume()` on the main UI thread:

```
public async Task SetupDatabaseAsync()
{
  await CreateTableAsync<Session>();
  await CreateTableAsync<Speaker>();
}
```

Here's the alternative:

```
public void SetupDatabaseAsync()
{
  var t1 = CreateTableAsync<Session>();
  var t2 = CreateTableAsync<Speaker>();

  Task.WaitAll(t1, t2);
}
```

But from my understanding `Task.WaitAll()` should block the UI thread while waiting, thus leading to a deadlock. But it works just fine. Is that because the two calls don't actually invoke anything on the UI thread?

What's the difference if I use `Task.WhenAll()` instead? My guess it that it would work even if the UI thread would be invoked, just like with `await`.

Comment: Your examples aren't the same, the first only starts the second task after the first completes.

Comment: Why you think that blocking UI thread will cause deadlock?

Comment: @Lee Exactly. That's why I wrote that to optimize and let them execute in parallel, the method is changed to use Task.WaitAll().

Comment: @HamletHakobyan Well, it is *really* easy to do given the use of `await`.  You only need to synchronously wait on a task that uses `await`.

Comment: For a deadlock to happen, some conditions have to be met: -Mutual exclusion -Resource holding -Circular wait And -No preemption.

If one of then is missing you won't have a deadlock. You're examples don't give that much info though.

Comment: @Servy Of course, in case, if await captured synchronization context, we will get deadlock. But my question was for OP who can answer to that.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I describe the [details of the deadlock situation](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) on my blog. I also have an [MSDN article on `SynchronizationContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg598924.aspx) that you may find helpful.

In summary, `Task.WaitAll` will deadlock in your scenario, but only if the tasks need to sync back to the UI thread in order to complete. You can conclude that `CreateTableAsync<T>()` does not sync back to the UI thread.

In contrast, this code will deadlock:

```
public async Task SetupDatabaseAsync()
{
  await CreateTableAsync<Session>();
  await CreateTableAsync<Speaker>();
}

Task.WaitAll(SetupDatabaseAsync());
```

I recommend that you *not* block on asynchronous code; in the `async` world, sync'ing back to the context is the *default* behavior (as I describe in my [`async` intro](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html)), so it's easy to accidentally do it. Some changes to Sqlite.Net in the future may (accidentally) sync back to the original context, and then any code using `Task.WaitAll` like your original example will suddenly deadlock.

It's best to use `async` "all the way":

```
public Task SetupDatabaseAsync()
{
  var t1 = CreateTableAsync<Session>();
  var t2 = CreateTableAsync<Speaker>();
  return Task.WhenAll(t1, t2);
}
```

"Async all the way" is one of the guidelines I recommend in my [asynchronous best practices article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

When you're blocking the UI thread (and the current synchronization context) it will only cause a deadlock if one of the tasks that you're waiting on marshals a delegate to the current context and then waits on it (synchronously or asynchronously).  Synchronously blocking on *any* async method isn't an instant deadlock in every single case.

Because `async` methods will, by default, marshal the remainder of the method to the current synchronization context and after every single `await`, and because the task will never finish until that happens, it means that synchronously waiting on methods that use `async/await` will often deadlock; at least unless the described behavior is explicitly overridden (through, say `ConfigureAwait(false)`).

Using `WhenAll` means that you're not blocking the current synchronization context.  Instead of blocking the thread you're just scheduling another continuation to be run when all of the other tasks finish, leaving the context free to handle any other requests that are ready *right now* (like, say, the continuation from the underlying `async` method that `WhenAll` is waiting on).

Comment: You say `WhenAll` is not blocking. But why isn't `WaitAll` either?

Comment: I feel like I need a better understanding about synchronization contexts. Any reading recommendations?

Comment: @Krumelur Start with the documentation of the class on MSDN, as you would for pretty much any class you're curious about.

Comment: @Krumelur Why does `WaitAll` block?  Because it was coded to block.  It's *purpose* in life is to block until the tasks finish.  `WhenAll` just creates a new tasks, which takes almost no time at all, and then returns basically right away, letting execution continue on its merry way doing...whatever it is code does these days.

Comment: @Krumelur, as recommends Servy the MSDN is good start. Also you can explore the Stephen Toub blog.

Comment: @Servy, I never used `WhenAll`, but I think there is no reason to use it without contiuation. Isn't it?

Comment: @Servy I know `WaitAll` *blocks*. But in my example above it does not. The UI stay responsive while it is waiting, even if I add a third long running task to wait for. The method is called from `async OnResume()` with `await SetupDatabaseAsync()`. Are you saying that it *is* blocking but not the UI thread?

Comment: @Krumelur, `WaitAll` blocks but it is depends to which tasks it waits. The answer is in implementation of `CreateTableAsync`. Because task returned by this method can ends very fast.

Comment: @Krumelur Yes, it does block.  It may not *deadlock*, due to type of asynchronous tasks you have, but it will *block*.  If it's not blocking your UI thread, then either it's finishing before you notice it, or you're not calling it from your UI thread.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this sample will demonstrate what might be happening. It's an iOS view loading. Try it with both the await call and without it (commented out below). Without any await in the function it will run synchronously and the UI will be blocked.

```
    public async override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad ();

        var d1 = Task.Delay (10);
        var d2 = Task.Delay (10000);

        //await Task.Delay (10);

        Task.WaitAll (d1, d2);

        this.label.Text = "Tasks have ended - really!";
    }

    public override void ViewWillAppear(bool animated)
    {
        base.ViewWillAppear (animated);
        this.label.Text = "Tasks have ended - or have they?";
    }
```

Comment: The issue isn't just about blocking the UI; it's about deadlocking.  Oh, and for the record, this code blocks the UI in *both* cases, not just one.