# Combine Results from Async Method and Return Synchronously

Tags: c#, azure, asynchronous, async-await

**I've read many posts where people have faced similar issues but they seem to make assumptions that don't apply or their code simply does not work for me.** I need to combine results from asynchronous methods. **The ONLY thing async that I want is the combining of the results.** Since the Azure Service Bus will only allow me to grab 256 messages at a time, I want to send off multiple requests to get a few batches at once and make it into one list.

> There seems to be an assumption that if you are calling an async
>   method you want to return to the caller while the work completed
>   (i.e.: some long running task). However, I don't want that at all. I
>   want to wait on the tasks to complete and then take my combined list
>   and return it.

Firstly I don't want to mark my calling method with async. I can but why should I, I am by all means calling an synchronous method that happens to be performing some asynchronous actions before getting back to me.

I have seen examples using WhenAll() and then working with the Result, but this doesn't work for me. I've tried all different permutations but it either locks up my app or it tells me the task hasn't been executed yet.

Here is what I have currently:

```
public IEnumerable<BrokeredMessage>[] GetCombinedResults()
{
            var job = () => ServiceBus.TrackerClient.ReceiveBatchAsync(BatchLimit);
            Task<IEnumerable<BrokeredMessage>> task1 = _retryPolicy.ExecuteAsync<IEnumerable<BrokeredMessage>>(job);
            Task<IEnumerable<BrokeredMessage>> task2 = _retryPolicy.ExecuteAsync<IEnumerable<BrokeredMessage>>(job);
            IEnumerable<BrokeredMessage>[] results = Task.WhenAll<IEnumerable<BrokeredMessage>>(task1, task2).Result;
            return results;
}
```

But calling results causes it to lock up. I've read deadlocks can occur doing this but have seen this proposed as an answer in other questions. **If I call Task.WaitAll() and care nothing on the results this type of setup works fine.** Not sure why this becomes difficult when I want the returned results from the tasks. I've tried using Task.Run but then it exits my method before ever getting the results.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You seem to be interested in using async for fan-out parallelism. That's a totally valid thing to do. It is not necessary to make the entire call chain async to make use of fan-out parallelism.

You stumbled over the usual ASP.NET deadlock. You can use `Task.Run` as a simple, fail-safe way to avoid it. First, let's make `GetCombinedResults` async to keep it simple and consistent:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<BrokeredMessage>[]> GetCombinedResultsAsync()
{
            var job = () => ServiceBus.TrackerClient.ReceiveBatchAsync(BatchLimit);
            Task<IEnumerable<BrokeredMessage>> task1 = _retryPolicy.ExecuteAsync<IEnumerable<BrokeredMessage>>(job);
            Task<IEnumerable<BrokeredMessage>> task2 = _retryPolicy.ExecuteAsync<IEnumerable<BrokeredMessage>>(job);
            IEnumerable<BrokeredMessage>[] results = await Task.WhenAll<IEnumerable<BrokeredMessage>>(task1, task2);
            return results;
}
```

This method is clearly correct. It does not mix sync and async. Call it like that:

```
var results = Task.Run(() => GetCombinedResultsAsync()).Result;
```

The reason this works is that `GetCombinedResultsAsync` executes without synchronization context now.

Comment: Thanks! I am still getting the hang of the async/await stuff. I'm still not sure why WaitAll() is so straightforward. I don't need the await keyword and the I don't have to mark the current method as async. I just create some tasks and say WaitAll(). If I want the results  after the tasks are completed suddenly I have to mark the current method as async. Seems odd.

Comment: I don't know why WaitAll does work. It should not. And the Task.Run thing definitely should work. Use the debugger to find out at what piece of code the hang starts. Or, comment out the Task.Run line and see if it works.; There is some relevant code that you have not posted yet. Post some more code.

Comment: @KingOfHypocrites: WaitAll() blocks the current thread to wait for all the tasks to complete so a deadlock could potentially occur depending on your synchronization context (UI and Asp.NET). usr's solution removes the synchronization context when executing your asynchronous method. See [this](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) and [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg598924.aspx) for a good explanation on synchronization context.

Comment: Why does `Task.WhenAll(...).Result` deadlock and `Task.Run(...).Result` doesn't? There might be no synchronization context inside `GetCombinedResultsAsync()` now, but there's one outside `Task.Run(() => GetCombinedResultsAsync()).Result`.

Comment: Rather than post all my code, you can see another place I use WaitAll in this example here: https://lostechies.com/ryansvihla/2014/08/28/cassandra-batch-loading-without-the-batch-keyword/ > Scroll to the bottom and look at the C# example. It batches up a bunch of tasks so it can write them all to the database at once. I use this same code and it works great. It doesn't require me to use the await or async keyword anywhere. But, it only works if I don't need to get to the results as I was saying in my question.

Comment: @PauloMorgado It is the continuation of the await call that will be synchronized on current synchronization context, hence the Task.Run(). Another solution would be to remove Task.Run() and use "await Task.WhenAll<...>(..., ...).ConfigureAwait(false); instead. It would result in the same behaviour. The ConfigureAwait(false) instructs the task to execute the continuation on the default scheduler (threadpool).

Comment: @KingOfHypocrites I am not sure why the Task.WaitAll() doesn't block in your case (see this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22699048/why-does-task-waitall-not-block-or-cause-a-deadlock-here)). Here is another [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/04/13/10293638.aspx) that shows best practices when doing "sync over async"

Comment: @Absolom, `Task.Run` has no benefit on ASP.NET. It can only hurt. On the other hand, it's not `Task.Run` or `Task.WhenAll` that blocks, but the returned task, And, if one deadlocks, the other will also deadlock.

Comment: @PauloMorgado using Task.Run this will not deadlock because nobody posts to the sync context anymore. The lambda body is unaware of any sync context. Waiting and blocking is not the problem per se. It is not a sufficient condition for deadlocking. For the same reason you can safely call blocking APIs such as Thread.Sleep and not deadlock or experience any other penalty. We have used blocking calls in ASP.NET for 15 years now and they still work.

Comment: @usr, "the lambda body" is unaware of any sync context, but the code calling `Task.Run` isn't. And that can deadlock, depending on the surrounding/caller code.

Comment: @PauloMorgado not in any way doe to the Wait call on the Task.Run task.

Comment: @PauloMorgado Please see the section **What if I really do need “sync over async”?** on this [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/04/13/10293638.aspx). Stephen Toub explains this exact case of using Task.Run() to avoid the synchronization context.