# calling several asynchronous methods and wait for the completion of all async methods

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I have one method called func1 and I need to call func2, func3, and func4 asynchronously from  func1 and task1 wait for all method's completion.

```
void func1()
{
    var task2 = func2();
    var task3 = func3();
    var task4 = func4();
    Task.WaitAll(task2,task3,task4);
}

async task<bool> func2()
{
}

async task<bool> func3()
{
}

async task<bool> func4()
{
}
```

Will all these methods in func1() will run asynchronously?

Comment: In short : yes they will

Comment: Or they [may deadlock](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22701188/15498), if any of them rely upon being able to get back into a single-threaded context (e.g. the UI thread) and `func1` was called in that same context.